# Marcar radiobutton em php

Tags: php

Como faço para deixar o radiobutton "checked" em PHP ? Estou tendo dificuldade com isso o nome do radiobutton é sexo e eu preciso fazer uma verificação no banco de dados se o sexo é 'M' ele marca um dos radioButton sexo senão ele marca o outro radioButton sexo. Já fiz o SELECT e ele me retornou o valor das outras variáveis normalmente, só quero saber como marca um radiobutton, meu codigo está errado ? Já verifiquei se a variavel está recebendo o valor de sexo corretamente e está, o código de condição está depois da criação dos radioButton, não consigo pensar em nada que esteja errado, só pode ser a maneira como estou marcando o radioButton.

```
 <label>Sexo:</label><input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M"/>
 <label>Masculino</label>

 <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F"/>
 <label>Feminino</label>

 if($vsexo == 'M')
 {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>sexo[0].checked = true;</script>";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>sexo[1].checked = true;</script>";
 }
```

Comment: o que é "confição"?

Comment: Checked ? marcar o radioButton

Comment: Ah... **condição**... Ao carregar o documento vc quer que ele esteja marcado de acordo com a informação recebida do banco de dados, certo?

Comment: É isso mesmo .!.

Comment: Sabe o que fazer para marcar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
<label><input value="M" type="radio" name="sexo" <?= $vsexo == 'M' ? 'checked="true"' : ''; ?>>Masculino</label>
<label><input value="F" type="radio" name="sexo" <?= $vsexo == 'F' ? 'checked="true"' : ''; ?>>Feminino</label>
```

Comment: Não deu certo..

Comment: Improvável :D. O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Deu certo agora, valeu chefia !

Comment: Não sei porque o seu codigo nao deu certo, mas eu fiz um parecido com o seu e deu certo:

Comment: <?php if($vsexo == 'M'){echo "checked";}?>

Comment: Isso dentro do input

Comment: Eu tinha escrito seu código errado, agora que vi o = sem a tag de php, não entendi pq

Comment: A título de informação: `<?= $vsexo == 'M' ? 'checked="true"' : ''; ?>` é exatamente a mesma coisa que `<?php if($vsexo == 'M'){echo "checked";} ?>`. Chama-se operador ternário [leia mais aqui](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/operador-ternario).

Comment: Eu percebi, tanto que fiz com o que eu mais conheço, vi exatamente a ideia desse codigo seu, mas eu errei o inicio dele, nao tinha reparado que nao tem php

Answer (score -2):

```
$sexo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT campo_sexo FROM tabeladedados"));
$sexo = ($sexo[0] || "M");
<?php
    if(strtolower($Sexo) == "M"):
?>
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" checked="checked" />
<?php
    else:
?>
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" />
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Já existem os radioButton, ali você está criando outro, eu quero verificar o valor da variável sexo e de acordo com o valor marcar um dos radios ja existentes